# CodeIgniter Transaction not working neither generating any error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I am trying to duplicate record having new ID with transaction, since table fields are supposed to be changed over the time and I don't want to change code every time fields are updated, that's why transaction is best choice I seems to have.

CodeIgniter code for transaction:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `prdct`
    SELECT * FROM `productsNew` WHERE `ID` = ? ", array($id));

$this->db->query("UPDATE `prdct` SET `ID` = ?, `type` = 'Return' WHERE `ID` = ? ", 
     array("Ret-".$id, $id));

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO productsNew SELECT * FROM prdct WHERE `ID` = ? 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE productsNew.intQuantity = productsNew.intQuantity + VALUES(intQuantity)",
array("Ret-".$id));

$this->db->query("DROP table prdct");

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
} else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

I am not getting any error, so don't know why its not running. User seems to have all required privileges from MySQL as well.